# How to create a list from filenames in a user specified directory in Python?

Tags: python, list, subprocess, raw-input

I want to create a new list in Python from filenames in a user defined directory .

I can't quite get my head around the subprocess syntax from the wiki and some of the commands using PIPE seem to be discouraged.

So I'd prompt to define which directory to load from:

`directory = raw_input("Path to directory: ")`

Then run `subprocess.check_output(["ls", "*eg*.txt"])` in the specified directory and place the output into `list1`.

Comment: I'd suggest using python `os` library to walk through the given directory, listing all the files. `subprocess` is an overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
import os
import glob

files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,'*.*')))
```

Comment: This method stores full paths, e.g. `['C:\\Temp\\ada.csv', 'C:\\Temp\\ae.csv']`

Answer (score 5):

You can just use function from standard library that does just what you want:

```
import os
list1 = os.listdir(directory)
print(list1)
```

Comment: This method only stores filenames, e.g. `['ada.csv', 'ae.csv']`

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -u
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from os import listdir
directory = raw_input("Path to directory: ")
files_dir =  listdir(directory)
newlist = []
for names in files_dir:
    if names.endswith(".txt"):
        newlist.append(names)
print newlist
```